# Returns max element of an array

Tags: javascript

How to return max element of a given array using the code structure below?

```
var array = [100, 0, 50]; 

function max(array) {
  // code
}
```

Thank You.

Comment: [Try this](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1CHWA_enIN642IN642&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=How+to+return+max+element+of+an+array+javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `Math.max.apply(Math, array)`

```
var array = [100, 0, 50];
```

Another solution

```
function max(array) {
    var max = array[0];
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length-1; i++) {
        max = max > array[i+1] ? max : array[i+1];
    }
    return max;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) (ES2015):

```
Math.max(...arr)
```

The spread operator is not yet available in all browsers and runtimes - check the [compatibility table](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#spread_(...)_operator).

Comment: I don't think it's right to start giving ES2015 suggestions to plain "javascript"-tagged questions without clearly stating it won't work in most places out of the box yet.

Comment: I've linked Kangax's compatibility table, which will stay up-to-date.